# C++ move on function return?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, c++17

I have the following code:

```
class Foo {
    public:
      Foo() {}
      explicit Foo(Foo &&other) noexcept {}

      static Foo from() {
        Foo f;
        return f;
      }
};
```

When I compile it with `g++ --std=c++17 move.cpp`, I get the following error:

```
move.cpp: In static member function 'static Foo Foo::from()':
move.cpp:8:12: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr Foo::Foo(const Foo&)'
     return f;
            ^
move.cpp:1:7: note: 'constexpr Foo::Foo(const Foo&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'Foo' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
 class Foo {
       ^~~
```

I thought the function should be moving Foo when the statement `return f` is compiled (so, it should use the declared move constructor, right?). But, it looks like it is looking for a copy constructor. Can someone please explain what is going on here?

EDIT: This question was marked duplicate for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872972/explicit-move-constructor). However, this question is asking about C++17, while the other one is about C++11/C++14. Therefore, this is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: Remove `explicit`

Comment: Doesn't C++17 require RVO in this context?

Comment: @水飲み鳥 RVO is an optional optimization and still requires move/copy constructor. Copy elision introduced in C++17 is not applied here since `Foo` has move constructor. It just should be implicit.

Comment: Also, because you define move constructor, you shall define move operator too.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872972/explicit-move-constructor

Comment: @Ivan According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision, RVO is not optional in C++17. NRVO is optional.

Comment: which g++ version is this?

Comment: @Ivan The link also says that the statement "RVO is an optional optimization and still requires move/copy constructor." is wrong on both accounts. (Edit: In C++17)

Comment: @VTT g++ version:

g++-7 (Homebrew GCC 7.2.0_1) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: **I don't think this is a duplicate.** The referred question is tagged with C++11/14 and in C++17 whole situation is quite different. As for this question, there is also another viable (and maybe for someone better) solution, namely, you can substitute `Foo f; return f`;` by `return Foo{};` and then you don't need to remove the `explicit` specifier, which may be useful for some other reason.